# Posting data to ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, html, http

I have an application into which I wish to allow users to enter login details for their own websites. One of authentication methods is 'forms'. The way I had envisaged it working, is the users entering the method & action of their login form, and the name/value for each credential item, e.g. one for username, one for password. My application would then post this data in order to simulate a login, get the returned authentication cookie and be able to work on their site as if logged in.

In principle, this sounded like a reasonable kind of thing to do. However, as I'm sure you're aware, ASP.NET has a lot of inputs, and also hidden ones, e.g. __VIEWSTATE, which are all always posted back to the server whenever the ASP.NET form is submitted e.g. when a *real* user logs in. When my app tries to login however, it doesn't have the full list of inputs on that page, and their values, e.g. the always changing __VIEWSTATE.

My question: is there a way to post data to an ASPX page, posting *only* certain inputs, and excluding others, e.g. __VIEWSTATE?

If the page were, say, PHP it would probably look like this:

Ex. 1:

```
...
<div id="header">
    <form action="search.php" action="POST">
        <div id="search">
            <input type="text" name="query" id="SearchQueryText" value="Search query" />
            <input type="button" name=submit" id="SearchSubmitButton" value="Search!" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <form action="login.php" action="POST">
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="Username" value="Username" />
        <input type="text" name="passwd" id="Password" value="Password" />
        <input type="button" name=submit" id="LoginSubmitButton" value="Login" />
    </form>
    ...
</div>
...
```

in ASP.NET Web Forms, however, through the use of server controls, it'd probably look like:

Ex. 2:

```
...
<body>    
    <form name="AspNetForm" method="post" action="/Products/SomethingOrOther.aspx" id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="search">
                <input type="text id="ctl00$SearchComponent$SearchBox" name="ctl00$SearchComponent$SearchBox" value="Search query" />
                <input type="submit" id="ctl00$SearchComponent$SearchSubmit" name="ctl00$SearchComponent$SearchSubmit" value="Search!">
            </div>
            <div id="login">
                <input type="text id="ctl00$LoginComponent$Username" name="ctl00$LoginComponent$Username" value="Username" />
                <input type="text" id="ctl00$LoginComponent$Password" name="ctl00$LoginComponent$Password" value="Password">
                <input type="submit" id="ctl00$LoginComponent$LoginSubmit" name="ctl00$LoginComponent$LoginSubmit" value="Login">
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </form>
</body>
...
```

With example 1, submitting the login form is a simple case of POSTing uname=something&passwd=somethingelse to login.php, however, in ASP.NET, because all inputs are wrapped in a 'global' `<form>`, to submit the login inputs, you have to submit the global form, and therefore all the inputs.

So what I'm after, is a way to submit *only* certain inputs in that global form, e.g. not __VIEWSTATE, which we can't know without probing the page beforehand.

Comment: What about using webservices to make the authentication?

Comment: @jaderanderon Have each site expose authentication logic through a web service? Yes, in an ideal world this would be how I'd do it, however, I wish the system to be compatible with *all* forms auth systems e.g. custom built, ASP.NET login controls, etc., and the only thing all have in common is submitting user data through a form, which is standardized ((X)HTML/HTTP POST).

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX to post back the values to a specific page.  In general, Web Forms is designed to post back all data on the page when you trigger a server side event.  You then choose which elements/values to use in your code.  If you don't want to use view state on a element, you can disable it (e.g. EnableViewState=False).

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the page in which a login form appears, as that is on my customers web site/intranet, so disabling anything is not an option. We run the application (a different application on a different server) which has to interact with their login form. Using AJAX sounds interesting - would you mind elaborating a little please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net page same as asp classic.

In html action you can put the aspx page from and then you have to take that.

then you can use request object of asp.net to retrive data from form. Same you can create a html form in string and put that via putting it into panel control.

Then you can asp.net button as submit button.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow your method, however, I think you may have misunderstood my question. Having taken a look around, I found this article http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/213769-submit-html-form-programmatically that describes pretty well what I want to achieve. However, it does not address my issue re: ASP.NET. I've modified my question to better explain my problem.